# Action Pane Control Missing For Visual C# Items

Tags: c#, visual-studio

using Visual Studio Community Edition 2015

Created a new Office / Sharepoint VSTO Add in Project -> Excel 2013

Went to Project -> Add New Item -> Visual C# Items

I don't see Action Pane Control as an option.

I used the search online for template but nothing appears for Action Pane Control.

What needs to be done for Action Pane Control to appear an option?

Comment: and any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, however according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-an-actions-pane-to-word-documents-or-excel-workbooks?view=vs-2019) page, you can also add a `User Control`.

> You can alternatively add a User Control item to your project. The classes generated by the Actions Pane Control and User Control items are functionally equivalent.

Comment: Is there an actual "Action Pane" control in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: The link has "Add the user control to the actions pane" the original problem is that H Patel cannot see the actions pane. 4 years later his question does not have a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Word at least, the actions pane is available for document-level solutions only. You might want a Task Pane instead. It's basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application and project type
it says that Actions Pane is Document-level projects only (e.g. Word or Excel **application**).

(see [Features available by Office application and project type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/features-available-by-office-application-and-project-type))

For VSTO **Add-in** projects, it mentions Custom task panes as supported for Excel, Outlook, PowerPoint, and Word add-ins.

Follow these instructions:

1. [Custom task panes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes), and then
2. how to [Instantiate the custom task pane by passing the user control to the CustomTaskPaneCollection object in your VSTO Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpanecollection).

You don't have to instantiate it on the Addin startup event, you can use it on other events to show/hide your pane.